# Custom fields not showing on table output

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I'm having trouble figuring out why two custom fields are not showing up in transaction `VA05` (its output to be specific).

Before reading below: I didn't make any changes to the program because I wasn't assigned to this task. One of my colleagues did this change.

I followed [this](http://solidforms.de/en/extend-the-va05-and-va05n-with-additional-or-customer-specific-fields/) tutorial, which explains how to expand the `VA05` output table with custom fields. 
I didn't actually followed this guide. I followed this tutorial only to understand what my colleague might have done to achieve what we need and what might be needed to fix the issue.

So, as the tutorial suggests, this is what should be done in short:

- Go to `SE11` and search for `VBEP` Database table and click display.
- Click on `Append Structure`
- Click on `Create Append`
- Insert the name of the append name, in my case it's `ZZVBEP_MECC`
- Insert two fields: `ZZDELIVERYDATE` and `ZZREQDELIVERYDATE`
- Save and activate

If you go to `VBEP` table now, you'll see at the bottom the field `.APPEND` with the column `Data Element` set to `ZZVBEP_MECC`.

Now, following the tutorial, the include program `V05TZZMO` need to be changed, and here's ours:

```
***INCLUDE V05TZZMO .
* This form is called in the include LV05TFMO.
FORM MOVE_USERFIELDS USING ZP.
  CASE ZP.
    WHEN 'VBAK'.

    WHEN 'VBAP'.

      CHECK LVBAP-PSTYV NE 'ZRAC'.
      CHECK LVBAP-PSTYV NE 'ZCAC'.     "Escl.acconti
      MOVE LVBAP-KDMAT TO LVBMTV-ZZKDMAT.
      PERFORM OFFENE_AUFTRAGSMENGE.

     SELECT SINGLE * FROM VBKD WHERE VBELN = LVBAP-VBELN.
      IF SUBRC = 0.
      MOVE VBKD-KDGRP TO LVBMTV-ZZKDGRP.
      ENDIF.

    WHEN 'VBEP'.
      MOVE LVBEP-ZZDELIVERYDATE    TO LVBMTV-ZZDELIVERYDATE.
      MOVE LVBEP-ZZREQDELIVERYDATE TO LVBMTV-ZZREQDELIVERYDATE.
  ENDCASE.
ENDFORM.
```

When I run `VA05` however, these two custom fields are not there nor are in the `Change Layout` screen.

Is it possible that the code in `V05TZZMO` is not in the right place? Looking at the tutorial's code I saw that they put those statements in `WHEN 'VBAK'` instead of `WHEN 'VBEP'`.

Also, the `ENHANCEMENT 1 ZZ_SD_VBAK_VA05` is not present in my code.

---

There might be something I missed. As I said above, I didn't make these changes so I cannot tell exactly what my colleague did.

Comment: The tutorial doesn't say anything about `VBEP`. Could you edit and clarify your question pleas?

Comment: @SandraRossi That's the problem. I don't know whether what my collegue did was a mistake or else. What table should be used? `VBAK`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved.

Here's the procedure step-by-step we followed in order to fix the issue:

#### Create an `Append Structure`

- Go to TCode `SE11` and open database table `VBMTVZ`
- Click on `Append Structure...`(It's in the program's toolbar) - or `Goto > Append Structure`
- Create a new `Append Structure`(There's a button for it)
- Enter the name of the structure(in our case was `ZZVBMTVZ_MECC`
- A new structure is then created. Enter the needed components/fields
- Save and activate the structure.
- Note: To check if the structure is actually appended, go back and open table `VBMTVZ` again. At the end of the list of fields there must be one field called `.APPEND` with the type set to the name of the structure you created. After this field, there's also all your fields you created on that structure. See the image below for reference.

[image: Append structure reference]

#### Change `V05T` program

Now you'll need to make some changes to the program linked to the TCode `VA05`.

To do this:

- Go to TCode `SE80`.
- Select `Function Group` and insert `V05T` as the name of the group.
- Open the sub-folder called `Includes` and look for `V05TZZMO`
- Open this include file in `change` mode.
- The file should look like this:

```
***INCLUDE V05TZZMO .
* This form is called in the include LV05TFMO.
FORM MOVE_USERFIELDS USING ZP.
  CASE ZP.
    WHEN 'VBAK'.
*     header
*     MOVE LVBAK-XXXXX TO LVBMTV-ZZXXXXX.

    WHEN 'VBAP'.
*     item
*     MOVE LVBAP-XXXXX TO LVBMTV-ZZXXXXX.

    WHEN 'VBEP'.
*     schedule line
*     MOVE LVBEP-XXXXX TO LVBMTV-ZZXXXXX.

  ENDCASE.
ENDFORM.
```

Add the following line of code to the `WHEN 'VBEP'.` code block.

```
MOVE LVBEP-name_of_your_field TO LVBMTV-name_of_your_field
```

You need to add that line for each field you appended.

In my case, the final result was the following:

```
***INCLUDE V05TZZMO .
* This form is called in the include LV05TFMO.
FORM MOVE_USERFIELDS USING ZP.
  CASE ZP.
    WHEN 'VBAK'.
*     header
*     MOVE LVBAK-XXXXX TO LVBMTV-ZZXXXXX.

    WHEN 'VBAP'.
*     item
*     MOVE LVBAP-XXXXX TO LVBMTV-ZZXXXXX.

    WHEN 'VBEP'.
*     schedule line
*     MOVE LVBEP-XXXXX TO LVBMTV-ZZXXXXX.

  move LVBEP-zzdeliverydate to lvbmtv-zzdeliverydate.
  move LVBEP-zzreqdeliverydate to lvbmtv-zzreqdeliverydate.

  ENDCASE.
ENDFORM.
```

---

Save the file and activate the program.

At this point you should be able to see your fields in the output of TCode `VA05`.

---

#### Notes

In order to be able to change the include program `V05TZZMO` you need an Access Key. Without that you cannot change the program.

If the fields you appended aren't showing even after activating, try:

- To logout and log back in or
- reset the buffer with this TCode `/$SYNC`

Comment: But *removing everything* is not a good option, it can broke something old in the future. To make the answer valuable it would be better to fing the reason why it was not working and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Custom fileds also must be included in the structure ***VBMTVZ***.

Regards

Comment: Structure `VBMTVZ` does contains these two custom fields.